# How to close All fragments with activity programmatically using Jetpack navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

[image]

Here is scenario:

1. On login activity button click open Activity 2
2. In Activity 2 multiple fragments and navigate through navgraph
3. I want to go back on login screen while click on Fragment 3 Finish button

Here what I try but no luck:

```
findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_fragment3_to_fragment1,
                null,
                NavOptions.Builder()
                    .setPopUpTo(R.id.fragment1, true).build())
```

Comment: You can do   findNavController().popBackStack(fragment1Id, true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close Activity 2 using `finish()` and the fragments will be closed with the activity, to close Activity 2 from Fragment 3 you can use this line of code inside Fragment 3:

```
requireActivity().finish()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, add attributes `app:popUpTo='your_nav_graph_id'` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` to the action tag.

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/signInFragment"
android:name="com.glee.incog2.android.fragment.SignInFragment"
android:label="fragment_sign_in"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sign_in" >
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_signInFragment_to_usersFragment"
    app:destination="@id/usersFragment"
    app:launchSingleTop="true"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

Second, navigate to the destination, using above action as parameter.

```
findNavController(fragment).navigate(
 SignInFragmentDirections.actionSignInFragmentToUserNameFragment())
```